# Nillable on @XmlAnyElement

Tags: jaxb

I made a general class for plural elements for JAXB.

```java
@XmlTransient
public abstract class Plural<S> {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Collection<S> singulars;
}
```

With following classes,

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Item {

    //@XmlValue // problem with xsi:nill and ""
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private String name;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Items extends Plural<Item> {
}
```

When I declare the `name` as `@XmlEement(nilalble = true)`, it works fine. But `@XmlValue` makes some problem between `xsi:nil` and `""`.

Is there any way to set `nillable = true` on `@XmlAnyElement`?

UPDATE ----------------------------------------------------------

When `Item#name` annotated with `@XmlElement`, following XML marshalls and unmarshalls successfully.

```xml
<items xmlns="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind/test">
    <item id="-4939700912221365683">
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>name</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </item>
    <item id="-8544902644460968391">
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </item>
    <item id="525642804765733165">
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </item>
</items>
```

When `Item#name` annotated with `@XmlValue`, following output XML marshalls and unmarshals but failed on equality testing.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items xmlns="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind/test">
    <item id="7812630870400466385">name</item>
    <item>name</item>
    <item id="-1067677982428177088"/>
    <item id="5609376399324841172">name</item>
    <item id="-4755856949417090129"/>
</items>
```

Which seems `xsi:nil` omitted on each `item` element. So `Item#equals` failed on each Items. The `""` without `xsi:nill` parsed as empty element witch each came from `null`s. Is it just `@XmlValue`'s problem? @Blaise Doughan I learned about `@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)` from your blog entry anyway. Thanks.

And here comes what I want it be.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns="http://jinahya.googlecode.com/xml/bind/test">
    <item id="7812630870400466385">name</item>
    <item>name</item>
    <item id="-1067677982428177088" xsi:nil="true">
    <item id="5609376399324841172">name</item>
    <item id="-4755856949417090129" xsi:nil="true">
</items>
```

Comment: Which element do you want to have the `xsi:nil` attribute on it and what do you want it to mean?  Can you update your question with the XML document you are trying to produce/consume?

Comment: @bdoughan I hope it's not too late. I added an XML code that I want to generate. Thank you.

Comment: I got back to this problem again, recently.

Comment: Hello, Mr. @bdoughan.